# Trying to implement a WOPIHOST

Tags: c#, tcp, ms-wopi

I have downloaded a significant number of samples but with limited success. Many from GitHub.  I am trying now, at the simplest, to simply have a listener (which i downloaded) that will parse the WOPI Request.  My listener will listen for anything on port 8080.  To test the listener, if I access the url http://localhost:8080/sometest my listener responds. Awesome. But when I try to access my wopi host with this url:

```
http://<my 2016 owa not on my local box>/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx?WOPISrc=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a8080%2fwopi%2ffiles%2ftest.xlsx&access_token=rykC%2fPgFQOs%3dRJT%2fPULGbsyZKGVnQmcO5tqJgEKoY3MIfAE3sh15shw%3d
```

My listener is not called.  Shouldn't the listener be receiving a message from my OWA 2016 server?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: put your server's IP into the url instead of *localhost*

Comment: Exactly, if your OWA server doesn't run on the exact same machine as the listener, `localhost` won't work. You have to use either IP or hostname of your machine.